# Seen Posts Reverse Relationship Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So, I am creating a social media like rails app, where you have posts created by users. And I want to add a 'seen by' feature in it.

Basically, I want to create a relationshp, where I have 
`has_many :seen_posts` in the users model. And a `has_many :seen_by` in the live_feed table.

But I want to manage this by creating only one join table. Every time the user clicks on the post, an api is called and the post is appended to the users seen_posts array. And it is reflected when i call `@user.seen_posts`.

But how do I inverse this to get the same result, if i call `@post.seen_by`. 
It really doesnt seem right to create a second join table and append both at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using has many through:

**user.rb**

```
has_many :seen_posts, through: :relationships, source: :seen_post
```

**live_feed.rb**

```
has_many :seen_by, through: :relationships, source: :user_seeing
```

**relationship.rb**

```
belongs_to :user_seeing, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :seen_post, class_name: "Live_Feed"
```

With this approach you need to generate a migration with the "relationship" table and the respective foreign keys.